# Failed to run new ios xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Yosemite 10.10.3 installed with Xcode 6 downloaded from Mac App Store. When I try to execute one Single view application project, newly created, without modify anything, I get the following error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Have I to install anything? Any idea of what's happening?

(Xcode newbie)

Answer (score 0):

That could mean a few things, did you make sure to make the first view the "initial view controller"?

Is there any other error message or is there somewhere in your code that caused an error?

Comment: Whats "initial view controller"?

Comment: when you are clicked on your View Controller in storyboard, on the right hand side there is an option to make it the initial view controller, this tells xcode to make this view controller the first thing you see when you press "play"